# Hi everyone, I have a question about Jenkins pipeline and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I have a pipeline which build an image, push it to AWS ECR, and the last stage of my pipeline is a sh command that build the service in AWS ECS. is there a way to push the name of the image that Jenkins created to my cloudformation stack, in order to complete the task automatically ?

```
    stage('Build image') {
      steps {
        script {
          myapp = docker.build("${LOCATION}/${AWS_REPO_NAME}:${env.BUILD_ID}")
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Run image') {
      steps {
          withAWS(region:'${REGION}',credentials:'demo-ecr-credentials') {
          sh "aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${LOCATION}/v2/"
          sh "docker push ${LOCATION}/${AWS_REPO_NAME}:${env.BUILD_ID}"
        }
      }
    }


    stage('Build ECS') {
      steps{
        script {
          sh 'aws cloudformation deploy --template-file cloudformation.yml 
           --stack-name jenkinstack '
         }
       }
     }    
   }
 }
```

Here's a part of my Cloudformation stack:

```
TaskDefinition:

Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'

DependsOn:

  - VPC

Properties:

  ContainerDefinitions:

    - Name: test

      Cpu: '100'

      Memory: "0.5GB"

      Essential: 'true'

      Image: !Join

        - ''

        - - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'

          - .dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

          - hello-world

          - ':'

          -  **${env.BUILD_ID}** 

      Memory: '300'

      PortMappings:

        - HostPort: 80

          ContainerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a parameter for the image name in cloud formation stack(i.e in the yml format)

`--parameter-overrides` by using this you can pass the corresponding value generated by jenkins.

Comment: Can you please provide a short example.